# Do we need more moderator involvement on the site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Assuming many users won't read this, but if you do, please chime in,  I check in on the site frequently, finding the queue empty and nothing to do and still managed to get an email from Stackexchange Community Support saying I need to step up moderation.  The other site I moderate, Christiantiy.SE has quite a bit to do every day, but here not so much.

However, we could be more particular about the kind of content we allow on the site, we could start asking people to up their game on posts where all we see is some code and "have you tried this"?  We could start demanding explanations for *why* things you try are the things that work and delete answers that fail to meet some criteria.

But we definitely don't want to do it without any community support or else we'll just crush the site with red tape and annoy everyone.